# Ubuntu Dual Boot - Graphics Device Startup issue

Tags: boot, drivers, dual-boot, 22.04, graphics

I am completely new to dual booting Ubuntu with Windows and Linux in general. Now I just downloaded Ubuntu 22.04 with Rufus and did the disk partitioning of 30 GB (went safe) and everything that all the guides told me to. But after starting Linux and getting to the "Try or Install Ubuntu" screen and pressing enter my computer just gets a permanent terminal error screen after like 10 seconds. The error message is:

```
i915 0000:00:02.0: 
Your graphics device 7d55 is not properly supported by i915 in this kernel version.  
To force driver probe anyway, use i915.force_probe=7d55.
```

Nothing I press on the terminal screen does anything. I can only manually power down the laptop and the run Windows.

I have no idea how to do the "force driver" thing and my research only figured out the my laptop released 2024 and has the newer graphics card Intel Arc with ID: 7D55. The model is an HP Spectre x360 2in1 14.

Anybody know anything that could help me fix this issue? I would love to be able to dual boot but can't get past that error screen.

[image]

I hope I can use Ubuntu now, but is it possible I have to wait for 24.04 LTS in April if nothing else works?

Edit: I downloaded the latest ubuntu 22.04.4. According to this site discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-notes/24668 - "Ubuntu Desktop will automatically opt-into v5.17 2.6k kernel on the latest generations of certified devices (linux-oem-22.04).". Yet I can't find how to update the kernel without being able to run linux, so only using windows...

Comment: Where do i find the kernel stack I am using? I downloaded the latest ubuntu 22.04.4. According to this site https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/jammy-jellyfish-release-notes/24668 - "Ubuntu Desktop will automatically opt-into v5.17 2.6k kernel on the latest generations of certified devices (linux-oem-22.04)." Does that help?

Comment: It was the top one i could download on this site https://ubuntu.com/download/desktop

Comment: @guiverc any advice?

Comment: I'm not familiar with your issue, nor GPU so can't really advise. "*Latest 22.04.4*" isn't specific (there are ISOs of 22.04.4 with the 5.15 kernel, and with 6.5 kernel but you don't specify; plus not all ISOs include OEM kernels; filename of ISO would have been clearer than the page that has multiple ISOs available). If it was me I'd likely boot a *noble* [24.04] ISO using the 6.8 kernel (*it's been available for some time with 6.8 RC4*) and see if it's the answer; but *noble* isn't on-topic on this site (support is on-topic at [UF](https://ubuntuforums.org/) & elsewhere though).

Comment: Could you find a link to where i could download 22.04.4 with 6.5 kernel @guiverc? I cant find it anywhere, and I've been looking everywhere i know of. filename btw: "ubuntu-22.04.4-desktop-amd64". Keep in mind that i only have windows now but need a way to, via windows, get ubuntu 22.04 with a newer kernel than 6.0 to run with my graphics driver

Comment: The Ubuntu 22.04.4 Desktop ISO you mention comes with the 6.5 kernel, 22.04.3 Desktop had 6.2, 22.04.2 Desktop had 5.19 & Ubuntu Server 22.04 ISOs inc. 22.04 & 22.04.1 Desktop (but that would upgrade; only *flavors* defaulted to GA at 22.04 & 22.04.1) used the 5.15 kernel. Desktop ISOs include OEM, and *noble* only uses 6.8 by default.